# gapi.client.setApiKey undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to build a safari extension using the Google Javascript API. I am trying to follow the following guide.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js

Currently debugger is failing on the handleClientLoad with error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'gapi.auth.authorize')".

Not sure what is causing this as I am following Google own example.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Your Client ID can be retrieved from your project in the Google
      // Developer Console, https://console.developers.google.com
      var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';

      var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];

      /**
       * Check if current user has authorized this application.
       */
      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
            'immediate': true
          }, handleAuthResult);
      }

      /**
       * Handle response from authorization server.
       *
       * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
       */
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
          loadGmailApi();
        } else {
          // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
          // clicking authorize button.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
        }
      }

      /**
       * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
       *
       * @param {Event} event Button click event.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
          handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      /**
       * Load Gmail API client library. List labels once client library
       * is loaded.
       */
      function loadGmailApi() {
        gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', listLabels);
      }

      /**
       * Print all Labels in the authorized user's inbox. If no labels
       * are found an appropriate message is printed.
       */
      function listLabels() {
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
          'userId': 'me'
        });

        request.execute(function(resp) {
          var labels = resp.labels;
          appendPre('Labels:');

          if (labels && labels.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
              var label = labels[i];
              appendPre(label.name)
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No Labels found.');
          }
        });
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('output');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="authorize-div" style="display: none">
      <span>Authorize access to Gmail API</span>
      <!--Button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
      <button id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">
        Authorize
      </button>
    </div>
    <pre id="output"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: API key is used when requesting public data,   client id is used with Oauth2 requests.   Normally you wouldn't combine the two, did you create both types of credentials in Google developer console.

Comment: @DaImTo : Yes I did, I also modified the post and now I am getting a new error with gapi.auth.authorize.